# gfortran destructor of members

Tags: fortran, gfortran, derived-types

I noticed a strange linking error with gfortran (GNU Fortran (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2) that depends on the order in which I define members in a derived type. With ifort (ifort (IFORT) 18.0.1 20171018), the code compiles and behaves as expected.

```
module bug

  implicit none
  type indestructable
    integer :: i
  end type
  type destructable
    integer :: i
  contains
    final :: destruct
  end type destructable

  type compound
    type(destructable) :: des
    type(indestructable) :: ind
  end type compound

contains

  subroutine destruct(instance)

    type(destructable), intent(in) :: instance
    write(*,*) instance%i

  end subroutine destruct

  subroutine run

    type(compound) :: cmp

    cmp%des%i = 3
    cmp%ind%i = 4

  end subroutine run

end module bug

program main
  use bug, only: run
  implicit none
  call run
end program main
```

This program should print out '3' on finalization, because the 'des' in 'cmp' has a destructor that writes out its member 'i', which was set to 3.

In gfortran, the compiler gives an error that the destructor of type compound is not defined. This destructor should be automatically generated and call the destructors of all the members. The problem is that there is also a member of a type without destructor in the compound type. And this somehow hampers gfortran with the organization of the destructors.

This issue is solved by putting the destructable member after the indestructable member (switching the two lines inside the type definition of compound).

Does anyone know if this is a compiler issue that may be solved in later versions, or am I doing something wrong and ifort somehow fixes it for me. I always learned that the order in which member variables are defined should not matter.

For anyone encountering the same problem: "Always put your destructable members at the end". However, non-derived types do not seem to matter, even if they are allocatable.

Comment: Might be a bug in the mentioned version (GCC 4.9.2 released [2014-10-30]), I tried with gfortran 7.3.0 on Windows (so not really comparable), but I didn't see the problem.

Comment: gfortran supposedly does not yet [fully support finalization](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37336).

Comment: The main thing in gfortran that is not finalized are the function results, but those are not used here.

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely [bug 58175](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58175), resolved fixed in GCC 7. Update your GCC. I can confirm your code compiles in this version.